# Multiple elements with same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

On the website that I am scraping there are 2 elements with the same class `('ul', class_='list')`.

When I run:

```
syn = soup.find('ul', class_='list')
print(syn.text)
```

I just get the text of the first element with the class `('ul', class_='list')`

How can I make it so that I get the text of the second element with the same class name?

(I have tried searching around but I can't seem to find the answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `find_all` :

```py
syn = soup.find_all('ul', class_='list')
```

Edit:

As @barmar mentioned, find_all will return a list so you would need to handle it accordingly :

```py
syn = soup.find_all('ul', class_='list')
for ul in syn:
    print(ul)
```

Comment: If you don't add more details, I guarantee that they won't figure out that they need to add a loop to process the results.

Comment: `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I edited the reply to include your explanation.

Comment: `print(ul.text)`